# Class not found for a new module/service I am building. I am not sure how to debug

Tags: event-subscribers

I am building a new service, an event subscriber in a custom module. My class which extends EventSubscriberInterface is not being found.

> [error]  Class
>   Drupal\fivewire_commerce\EventSubscriber\fivewire_commerce_orderStateSubscriber
>   does not exist

I am not sure why and am struggling to debug what I have done wrong.

My module is 'fivewire_commerce'.

/modules/custom/fivewire_commerce

I have created a file to delare my service.

/modules/custom/fivewire_commerce/fivewire_commerce.services.yml

```
services:
  fivewire_commerce.order_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\fivewire_commerce\EventSubscriber\fivewire_commerce_orderStateSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: 'event_subscriber' }
```

And this is my class

/modules/custom/fivewire_commerce/EventSubscriber/fivewire_commerce_orderStateSubscriber.php

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\fivewire_commerce\EventSubscriber\fivewire_commerce_orderStateSubscriber
 */

namespace Drupal\fivewire_commerce\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Drupal\state_machine\Event\WorkflowTransitionEvent;

/**
 * Event Subscriber MyEventSubscriber.
 */
class fivewire_commerce_orderStateSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        // Trigger after an order is made
        $events['commerce_order.place.post_transition'][] = ['onCompletedOrders'];
        return $events;
    }

    /**
     * Code that should be triggered when an order is placed.
     * This is the order state 'validation' according to our chosen workflow.
     */
    public function onCompletedOrders(WorkflowTransitionEvent $event) {
        $test =true;
//        if ($event->getToState()->getId() == 'validation') {
//
//        }
    }

}
```

And if I try to rebuild my cache I get:

> [error]  Class
>   Drupal\fivewire_commerce\EventSubscriber\fivewire_commerce_orderStateSubscriber
>   does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And this is my class
>
> /modules/custom/fivewire_commerce/EventSubscriber/fivewire_commerce_orderStateSubscriber.php

Autoloading relies on your classes being in a root /src folder for the module.

So move the file to

> /modules/custom/fivewire_commerce/src/EventSubscriber/fivewire_commerce_orderStateSubscriber.php

And PHP will be able to find it.